# how to create two different form to customer registration magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have to create two registration form to customer. I don't know what to override and how to proceed to do that. I really want your help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.php

```
This file content you copy it from : 

vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml
```

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register2.php

```
Your 2nd form goes here !
```

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_2" template="Magento_Customer::form/register2.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: really thanks for your replay i was asking about that with different ways in this blog but no one answered me really thank you very much and i will try this immediatly

Comment: just one question i overrided the register.phtml and i created a module to have a new route to the second form because what i have to do is that when the customer choose a  button radio (client local or client export) he will be redirected to one of this form so how to do to have the register2 under my module and not under the Customer_module

Comment: What is th path of your module ?

Comment: Mdweb/inscription

Comment: and the route is newcut/index/index

Comment: Just add `<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register_2" template="Magento_Customer::form/register2.phtml"/>` in `newcut_index_index.xml` the `register2.phtml` you should keep it in `Magento_Customer`

Comment: ok i will check that  brother :)

Comment: If you are using a Magento register form, you should put it in `Magento_Customer` otherwise if you are using a custom form without extending magento customer $block, you can put it directly in your custom module.

Comment: yes i am using magento register form but i have to  have some different attributs displayed in each form  and when i tried to just copy in register 2  the same as register.phtml i have nothing but now everything is ok thanks to you  :)

Comment: You're welcome, good luck

Comment: thanks Prince just one question i have the form  but why not having the new attributs that i added  like in form 1 ??

Comment: You should also get it, you can add it manually with the right name class etc `<input...>`

Comment: I have added 3 attributs and i called them in register1 and they are shown correctly but when i copied the same code to register 2 i just have the form without new attributes

Comment: Yes, because that attributes ares added automatically when you created them in setup script only for register.phtml, add them manually to register 2

Comment: i am sorry but what do you mean by manually ?

Comment: now i am having in the register.phtml a duplicated form :o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85084/discussion-between-prince-and-developper-magento).